# How to use the generated script from SQL 2005 to MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sqlyog

We are converting our database to MYSQL from MSSQL 2005.

Someone told me this is possible by generating a script in MSSQL using Database Publishing Wizard. I already created a script. Then by dragging it to the Query Writer in MYSQL. I am currently using SQLyog for creation of database.

How can I use that script to create a MYSQL file?

I also tried to use demo versions of converting tools but to no avail.

Please help me. =)

Comment: You could import the data directly using the Import External Data option in SQLyog. It would be much faster than converting a script.

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple or quick way to do a task like this. THe two database have differnt syntax and differnt datatypes, etc. I certainly would not trust a converting tool as you may want to make changes to fix bad design choices in SQL server to better choices in MYSQL.

Take your script and then run each section and find where it fails and then look up the correct syntax for mySQL and fix it.

Here is alink to a book you need to have for this conversion project as it wil show the syntax differnences:

[http://www.amazon.com/SQL-Nutshell-OReilly-Kevin-Kline/dp/0596518846/ref=sr_1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1330382519&sr=1-2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596518846)